# How do I change bookmark folder icon in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I have searched all over and can not seem to find a way to change the standard blue/grey bookmark icon (not page favicons) in Google Chrome bookmark bar.  Using a Mac.  Does anyone know?

Comment: You could try finding the resource file inside the app package, but it'd get overwritten with every update.

Comment: I looked in there,  but could not seem to see anything that might be related to the bookmark bar.